# Can firebase remote config used for iOS app force update feature?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-remote-config

I plan to use firebase remote config to implement force update feature to iOS app.  I set minimum allowed app version to remote config and the iOS app fetches it at launch.

What I'm worried about is that if app fetches the value at launch even remote config's throttling value is set long.

I don't need the minimum allowed app version set in remote config to update apps being run but I need to make sure it is updated at launch.

Does remote config updates values at every app launch even throttling value is set long?